# Why I can not set a position for an ImageView on the layout with programming

Tags: android

Why I can not set a position for an `ImageView` on the layout with programming?
when I run the following code when I click on the `ImageView` object it should go to another place but it stays in the same place. Note I know there are methods like the `setX()` or `setY()`, but I am using the API 7.

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/aaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />
```

And

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
            params.leftMargin = 30;
           imageView.requestLayout();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i bet you will have to set layout params after change:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
params.leftMargin = 30;
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Thank you, but are you sure you? because the result did not change.

Comment: try add something like this `layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.FALSE);`

Comment: it is possible margin and centering can interact in a way, you don't want

Comment: Thank you, Your code is correct and we should use the allowed values for that.